# Spring Data JPA - Consulta via Specification - ManyToMany e Join com várias Entidades

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jpa

Olá, montei a seguinte classe Specification:

```
public class ItemVendedorSpecification implements Specification<ItemVendedor> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    CategoriaRepository categoriaRepository;

    @Autowired
    FabricanteRepository fabricanteRepository;

    @Autowired
    VendedorRepository vendedorRepository;

    private String descricao;

    private List<Long> categorias;
    private List<Long> fabricantes;
    private List<Long> vendedores;

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    public ItemVendedorSpecification(String descricao, List<Long> categorias, List<Long> fabricantes, List<Long> vendedores) {
        super();
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.categorias = categorias;
        this.fabricantes = fabricantes;
        this.vendedores = vendedores;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ItemVendedor> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        if (!descricao.isEmpty()) {
            String PalavraChave[] = descricao.split(" ");
            for (String filtro : PalavraChave) {
                predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(root.get("id").get("produto").get("descricaoDetalhada")), "%" + filtro.toUpperCase() + "%"));
            }
        }

        predicates.add(builder.isTrue(root.get("disponivel")));

        if(!fabricantes.isEmpty()) {
            predicates.add(root.get("id").get("produto").get("fabricante").get("id").in(fabricantes));
        }

        if(!vendedores.isEmpty()) {
            predicates.add(root.get("id").get("vendedor").get("id").in(vendedores));

        }

        if(!categorias.isEmpty()) {
            predicates.add(root.join("id").get("produto").get("categorias").get("id").in(categorias));
        }

        return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[1]));
    }
}
```

Quase todos os predicares estão funcionando, exceto o que insere o critério de categorias. Ele não esta funcionando e estou tendo muita dificuldade para criar-lo.

Da forma que esta ele esta retornando o seguinte erro:

```
"Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.produto.categorias] of basic type; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.produto.categorias] of basic type",
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar na elaboração deste if?

Abaixo o detalhamento da classe ItemVendedor:

```
public class ItemVendedor implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private ItemVendedorPK id = new ItemVendedorPK();
    private BigDecimal preco;
    private Boolean disponivel;
    private Date dt_insert;
    private Date dt_update;
    private BigDecimal desconto;

    public ItemVendedor() {

    }

    public ItemVendedor(Produto produto, Vendedor vendedor, BigDecimal preco, BigDecimal desconto ,Boolean disponivel) {
        super();
        this.id.setProduto(produto);
        this.id.setVendedor(vendedor);
        this.preco = preco;
        this.disponivel = disponivel;
        this.desconto = desconto;
    }

//GETs and SETs
```

Como podem ver ela possui um campo chamado id que é uma chave composta pelos campos `Vendedor vendedor` e `Produto produto`.

Dentro da classe Produto tenho uma `List<Categoria> categorias`. Pois um produto pode pertencer a várias categorias.

Por sua vez a Classe categoria tem o `id`.

O que quero colocar na `Specification`, é uma forma de buscar todos os `ItemVendedor` que possuem dentro de sua lista de categorias alguma categoria que eu citei como parâmetro em outra lista `List<Long> categorias`.

Pessoal, estou colocando mais algumas informações para simplificar a compreensão, abaixo esta um diagrama de classes simplificado para entendermos o contexto da situação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como podem observar a classe Produto um produto pode ter várias categorias, e uma categoria pode possuir vários produtos.

O que eu pretendo fazer é o seguinte: Quero dar uma lista de valores do tipo Long que se referem a códigos de categorias. Este parâmetro é passado através de uma lista (`List<Long> categoriasId`) e será utilizado na seguinte consulta:

Quero que retorne todos os objetos do tipo ItemVendedor, onde, a lista de categorias do produto tem pelo menos 1 item que esta dentro da lista de parâmetros passada.

Esta abordagem esta sendo feita através de Specification devido tratar-se de uma consulta dinâmica, que irá agregar outros critérios conforme o código da classe.

Atenciosamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Estava utilizando a consulta de forma errada. Abaixo segue o código de resolução:

```
predicates.add(root.join("id").join("produto").join("categorias").get("id").in(categorias));
```

Para que conseguíssemos realizar a verificação para saber se o produto tinha alguma categoria que estivesse dentro do parâmetro foi necessário realizarmos alguns joins.

O primeiro Join é em relação ao que no código da classe esta como id, este campo na tabela ItemVendedor é na verdade uma classe para chave composta (`@Embeddable`), por sua vez esta classe tinha que realizar o join com a classe de Produtos, a qual possuía o campo de Categorias.

Assim conseguimos chegar até a lista de categorias de cada produto e assim comprar se temos algum elemento desta lista dentro do parâmetro de consulta informado.